# How to trap file access attempts with a filter driver (kernel) and offer dialog to allow/deny (user)?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, wdk

I've been looking at Windows's [File System Filter Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx).  I started with this "FsFilter" example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial

With effort, I managed to get it built and signed in versions that work on everything from 64-bit Win8 to 32-bit WinXP.  *(Well, as long as I run `Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON` to allow it to accept my test certificate, since I didn't pay Microsoft $250 to sign my .SYS file.  :-/)*

Now I want to modify FsFilter.  I'd like write accesses to certain types of files to be trapped by the filter.  I then want the user to receive a dialog box, in which they can either allow the access or deny it.

Perhaps obviously...the kernel-mode code cannot display the UI.  It will have to signal some user mode process, which will (after an arbitrarily latent period of time) signal back the user's wish to the driver.  I've looked a bit over 
[User-Mode Interactions: Guidelines for Kernel-Mode Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487414.aspx) (here's [Google's Cache as HTML](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aoh4AQmy-WqEJ%3adownload.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/KM-UMGuide.doc+windows+kernel+mode+notifications), instead of .DOC)

I don't know what the best way to attack this is.  The only example I've yet found to study is SysInternals FileMon.  The driver it installs gathers data in a buffer, which is periodically requested by the .EXE according to a WM_TIMER loop:

```
// Have driver fill Stats buffer with information
if ( ! DeviceIoControl( SysHandle, IOCTL_FILEMON_GETSTATS,
            NULL, 0, &Stats, sizeof Stats,
            &StatsLen, NULL ) )
{
    Abort( hWnd, _T("Couldn't access device driver"), GetLastError() );
    return TRUE;
}
```

Should I use a similar technique?  Perhaps the filter driver, upon receiving a request it wants to check, could place a record to track the request in a buffer that would contain two HEVENTs.  It would then WaitForMultipleObjects on these two HEVENTs, which represent a signaled "YES" or "NO" from user mode on whether to allow access.

Periodically the monitor process (running in user mode) will poll the driver from another thread using a custom IOCTL.  The filter driver would return the request information... as well as the two HEVENTs that request is waiting on.  The monitor would wait for the user's feedback, and when available signal the appropriate event.

I could also invert this model.  The user mode code could use a custom IOCTL to pass in data... such as HEVENTs which could be signaled by the driver, and just implement some kind of safe protocol.  This would eliminate the need for polling.

Basically just looking for guidance on method, or a working example on the web!  I'd also be interested to know what the mechanics would be on an asynchronous file access.  I assume there's a way so a client making an async call that is being checked could keep running and only be held up when they waited on the request to finish...?

---

*(Note: Along the way of getting the filters built and debugged, I learned there are some more modern techniques via "miniFilters"--which are part of something called the [Filter Manager Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538896%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  But for the moment, I'm not that concerned as long as the legacy model is supported.  It looks rather similar anyway.)*

Comment: Will still suggest to look at minifilters which has much simplified way of doing things. In nutshell, you can make request from kernel to user blocking to check for access and then allow/disallow the access.

Comment: @Rohan Ah...somehow I missed [that last talking point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538896%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the advantages: *"The filter manager provides common functionality for user-mode services and control programs that work with minifilter drivers. The filter manager user-mode library, Filterlib.dll, enables communication between a user-mode service or control program and a minifilter driver. Filterlib.dll also provides interfaces for management tools."*  May be exactly what I want, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *(a.k.a. I)* have pretty much enumerated the possibilities.  Either poll the way FileMon does, or pass an event.  Passing the event is probably a bit more error prone, and if you aren't a threading guru then there's probably more chance for error.  But if you tend to make lots of mistakes then device drivers may not be for you...skydiving might be a poor choice too.

I'll offer taking a look at this project, but please note the disclaimers in the README. *(It is only a test and investigation)*:

https://github.com/hostilefork/CloneLocker

And yes, to the extent that Microsoft and their driver model is to be something one worries about, miniFilters are the better choice these days.